# Using old MYSQL passwords with php 5.3

Tags: mysql, php-5.3

I have a problem where I am trying to connect to old database with new php5 and getting

```
mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password').
```

Everyone appears to solve this problem through making changes to either database config file or rehashing their passwords.

Catch is, I cannot do either at the moment. I would like to know if there is a way to make php5 use old passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraint, your only option is to [recompile PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php) against the `libmysqlclient` library (instead of the default, native PHP `mysqlnd`). Try the "Linux-Generic" "Development Libraries" binaries [provided by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads).

You might need to use an older version of `libmysqlclient`, I am not sure the newer versions still support the old authentication method.